# XML parser error: Not well formed in asp.net website with linux hosting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xml-parsing

I created a web site using VS2010 .NET Framework 4.0

I built the project and published it to the local file system. After uploading all published folders and files to the `public_html` directory. Whenever I hit on my domain I got following errors

1. Access forbidden to domainname.com
2. XML Parsing Error

   > XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
   >   Location: http://www.example.com/index.aspx
   >   Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page Title="My Website" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterHomePage.Master"
   >   -^

My `web.config` is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="" />
        <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="">
                <network host="" password="" userName="" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="None" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I don't see any option on godaddy linux hosting cPanel to configure asp.net

One more question I heard that I cannot host asp.net website on linux hosting. Is it true?

Comment: For now, ASP.NET **requires** a Windows machine with IIS - this won't be possible to host on Linux

Comment: thank you @marc_s.. can you suggest any alternatives to host a asp.net website on linux based hosting.?

Comment: If you want ASP.NET - you need to find a **Windows** hosting offer

Comment: thanks @marc_s.. this basics i should have known..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website hosts like godaddy are not able to support asp.net sites on a linux machine. If, however, you have your own linux server (dedicated or virtual) you may have success using [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/) though there are a number of limitations

**Supported Versions**

> Mono supports ASP.NET 2.0, ASP.NET AJAX and a handful of 3.5 controls.

**Limitations**

> Mono’s ASP.NET does not implement the following features:
>
> Precompiled updatable web sites.
>
> WebParts APIs.

Comment: thanks @5uperdan for your suggestion and reply..  so I need to use only php or html for websites if I want to upload them on linux based hosting.. there no other way out to put on a site developed on .net framework 3.5 or higher.?